# Running PHPmyadmin from inside a site dir

Tags: phpmyadmin

Say that instead of doing 46.101.215.108/phpmyadmin, I access PMA from a site directory, say:

judith-law.co.il/phpmyadmin

Does accessing PMA from a site dir (from whatever reason), has any influence on its work? In other words, should be problematic in any significant way?

Comment: No it should not as long as `judith-law.co.il` `maps` to `46.101.215.108`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it should not be an issue as long as `judith-law.co.il` maps to `46.101.215.108`.

This `46.101.215.108` is the way our computers think and `judith-law.co.il` is the way we humans think, so both are the same and will give no issues when you access `phpmyadmin` in either fashion.

Domain names map to `IP` addresses and a good example is `localhost` which maps to `127.0.0.1` on our local computers so calling or using `localhost` will have the computer resolve it to the `IP` address `127.0.0.1` or vice versa